# MBProgressHUB don't show in a modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

I show a modal view with a UITableView when I try to show the HUD (while I loading data), only can view the shadow of HUD, but it don't appears...

Comment: Show some of the code you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code to show how you are adding it to the current view, it will be hard for anyone to help you. With that, this is a snipped of code I am using in one of my apps, a modal UITableViewController that displays the MBProgressHUD while updating data.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
// Regiser for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = @"Creating Company";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Please Wait";
// Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(sendNewCompanyInformation) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did the HUD with SVProgressHUD, which works with modal windows (on iOS8 at least).